# jQuery each row items click append data html after 3rd items

Tags: jquery

I have a html code like below,
Each list have a class and a button, 
So while the user click the button, it should append a html using json and append after the 3rd items, The details is represent the item details, I had tried using nth-child, but it will make my each 3n+3 append the html, what I want is when the user click the 1,2,3 items it will append in after 3rd, when click on 4,5,6 item, it will append a details html on after 6.
Please ignore the data pulling. This is the way I using

**$('.item').eq(i % 3).after(html_details);**

Here is my Html

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">List 1</li>
    <li  class="item">List 2</li>
    <li  class="item">List 3</li>

    <!-- should append a html here -->

    <li  class="item">List 4</li>
    <li  class="item">List 5</li>
    <li  class="item">List 6</li>

    <!-- should append a html here -->
```

Here is my jQuery

```
$('.item').each(function(i){

    $(this).find('a').on('click',function(){

      var html_details = detailsTemplate(data[i]);

        console.log(i)

        $('.Details').remove();

        $('.item').eq(i % 3).after(html_details);

        $('.Details').hide();
        $('.Details').slideToggle();

      return false;

    })
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">List 1</a></li>
    <li  class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">List 2</a></li>
    <li  class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">List 3</a></li>

    <!-- should append a html here -->

    <li  class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">List 4</a></li>
    <li  class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">List 5</a></li>
    <li  class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">List 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

and:

```
$('.item').each(function(i) {
    $(this).find('a').on('click',function() {
        var html_details = '<li class="Details">DETAILS</li>'; //detailsTemplate(data[i]);

        $('.Details').remove();

        var index = (Math.floor(i / 3) * 3) + 2;

        $('.item').eq(index).after(html_details);

        $('.Details').hide();
        $('.Details').slideToggle();

        return false;
    })
})
```

Here is the corresponding [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arn9z6yb/).

Comment: Oh I just took your own code and make some little modifications!

Comment: :| I thought no ppl reply so I do my own version.
You can check out below, too many if statement hard understand also.

Comment: Didn't see it! Yes it's a little bit hard indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic can be this:

```
$('.item').eq(i + 3 - (i % 3) - 1).after(html_details);
```

Here is some explanations. `3 - (i % 3)` calculates how many items needed to skip ahead. Then you add up this number to current index `i` to get the item to append content after. I also added `- 1` in order to be able to use `after` instead of `before`, so it also works with the last item.

Check the demo below.

```js
$('.item').each(function (i) {
    $(this).find('a').on('click', function () {
        var html_details = detailsTemplate(data[i]);
        console.log(i + 3 - (i % 3) - 1)        
        $('.Details').remove();
        $('.item').eq(i + 3 - (i % 3) - 1).after(html_details);
        $('.Details').hide();
        $('.Details').slideToggle();
        
        return false;
    });
});

var data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
function detailsTemplate(d) {
    return '<div class="Details">' + (d + 1) + '</div>';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">List 1 <a href="">link</a></li>
    <li class="item">List 2 <a href="">link</a></li>
    <li class="item">List 3 <a href="">link</a></li>
    <!-- should append a html here -->
    <li class="item">List 4 <a href="">link</a></li>
    <li class="item">List 5 <a href="">link</a></li>
    <li class="item">List 6 <a href="">link</a></li>
    <!-- should append a html here -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh my god. This is smart.
I am using too many if statement for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loop rather than each for indexing. In your case

```
   for(var i=0;i<$('.item').length;i++)
    {
    $(this).find('a').on('click',function(){

          var html_details = detailsTemplate(data[i]);
                console.log(i)

            $('.Details').remove();
             if(i%3==0)
             {
                $('.item')[i].after(html_details);
              }
            $('.Details').hide();
            $('.Details').slideToggle();

        }
```

if you use .each() then you have to introduce count inside it and check count value

Comment: If we talking about the performance, the each loop will slower than for loop right?

Comment: there is not much difference in performance for short codes. but if you work in bulks then native javascript is faster than jquery functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.
But the way I use a bit noob. 
So I will change it more clean.

```
var details            = $('.details').html();
var detailsTemplate    = Handlebars.compile(details);
var detailsPlaceholder = $(this);

  $('.item').each(function(i){

    $(this).find('a').on('click',function(){

      $('.details').remove();

      var html_details = detailsTemplate(data[i]);
      var itemIndex = $(this).closest('.item').index()
      var itemWidth = $('.item').outerWidth(true)

      var position = $(this).closest('.item').offset().left

      tiles3(i,itemIndex);

      function tiles3(i,itemIndex){

          if(i%3 == 0){

              var left =  $('.item').length -  itemIndex;

              if(left == 1){

                $('.item').eq(i).after(html_details)

              } else if(left == 2) {

                $('.item').eq( (i%3) + i + 1 ).after(html_details)

              } else {

                $('.item').eq( (i%3) + i + 2 ).after(html_details)

              }

          } else if(i%3 == 1){

              var left =  $('.item').length -  itemIndex;

              if(left == 1){

                $('.item').eq(i).after(html_details)

              } else {

                $('.item').eq( (i%3) + i ).after(html_details)

              }

          } else {

              $('.item').eq( i ).after(html_details)

          }
      }

      return false;

    })

  })
}
```